# DNA extraction from plants and algae don't use phenol. Why?

Tags: molecular-biology, dna-isolation

I don't know if here is the correct place to make this question, but I've been noticing that protocols for the extraction of photosynthetic organisms DNA don't use phenol. Only CTAB / Chloroform.

Why?

Because bacterial or animal extraction are phenol:chloroform based.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CTAB is for removing polyphenols and polysaccharides which are found in plant tissues. Animal cells/bacteria don't have these. You can do an additional phenol-chloroform extraction if you want.

See [this protocol](http://www.monsanto.com/products/documents/dna-detection/dna_im.pdf) by Monsanto.

> 1. Weigh out 6g of processed tissue into a 50ml conical tube appropriate for centrifugation. Note: For unprocessed tissue, weighing
>      m ay occur prior to processing as long as entire processed sample is
>      transferred to the conical tube.
> 2. For each 6g sample add 25ml of a solution consisting of 24.25ml, pre-warmed (55°C) CTAB extraction buffer, 0.5ml 2-mercaptoethanol
>      (2-ME), and 0.25 ml of 10mg/ml proteinase K for a final concentration
>      of 2% (2-ME) and 100µg/ml (proteinase K).
> 3. Incubate the tube for 60 minutes at 55°C. Cool the tube briefly on bench (10 minutes)
> 4. Add 20ml of **phenol:chloroform:isoamyl alcohol** (PCI, 25:24:1).  Cap the tube and mix vigorously by vortex or inversion.
> 5. Centrifuge for 10 minutes at 13,000×g and 20-25°C to separate the aqueous and organic phases. Transfer the upper aqueous phase to a
>      clean 50ml conical tube.
> 6. Repeat extraction two times for a total of three extractions (steps 4-5).
> 7. Transfer upper aqueous phase to a new tube and add approximately 2/3 volume of -20°C isopropanol and gently invert the tube several
>      times to mix.
> 8. To precipitate the DNA place the tubes at -20°C for at least 30 minutes and up to three days.
> 9. To pellet the DNA centrifuge the tubes at approximately 13,000×g for 20 minutes at 4°C.
> 10. Redissolve the pellet in 4 ml of TE pH 8.0. Transfer to a 13ml Sarstedt tube and add approximately 40µl of 10mg/ml RNase, then
>       incubate at 37°C for 30 minutes.
> 11. To extract the DNA add 4ml of chloroform:isoamyl alcohol (CIA, 24:1).  Centrifuge for 10 minutes at approximately 13,000×g at room
>       temperature.  Transfer the upper aqueous phase to a clean Sarstedt
>       tube.
> 12. Repeat step 11 then add half volume of 7.5M ammonium acetate, gently mix by inversion/pipette and add 2 volumes of 100% ethanol. Mix
>       by inversion/pipette and place at -20°C for 30 minutes to overnight.
> 13. Centrifuge at 13,000×g for 20 minutes at 4°C to pellet the DNA.

Answer (score 1):

I have used phenol:chloroform many times for algal DNA and RNA extractions. These protocols needed only minor tweaks to adapt it to a particular species (some cell walls can be extremely though). The general principle behind phenol chloroform works on almost any sample once you have lysed/pulverised the cells. The only major issues occur when tissues are extremely fatty or full of carbohydrates.

I have also used CTAB but it seems to be less universally applicable to algal samples.